# Delete old database rows using cron?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database called `log_events`. In this table there is a column called `tags`. If there is a value of "`debug`" in that column and the date it was put in the database is more than 30 days, then that entry should be deleted. I will run the script via a cron. How can this be done using PHP please, any ideas? 
Thanks for any help, in advance.

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you written a MySQL driven app in PHP before?

Comment: Can you please be more specific where you are facing problems in PHP code, running the cron or SQL query ?

Comment: Hi, no I havn't any experience with php-mysql code. I am fairly new to php and can understand most of the basics, but not familiar with mysql at all yet. So would really apprieciate any help given... The cron part I can just setup with my hosting, its the actual code that I don't know. I beleive the date format for mysql is 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Query should look something like this

```
DELETE * FROM tbl_name WHERE column_name = 'debug' and created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAYS
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run a php script through cron or you can achieve your goal also with a simple BASH script :

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u user -pyourpassword dbname<<EOFMYSQL
DELETE FROM table WHERE tags = 'debug' AND date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAYS);
EOFMYSQL
```

then you can call the script in the crontab event.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: You are totally wrong. First, it depends on the context in which `NOW()` is invoked (see [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)). Second, you can safely compare values of type `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` with `NOW()`.